# Posting json string which contains &pound;

Tags: php, json, vb6, url-encoding

I have a VB6 application that is creating a JSON string and posting it to a website (PHP5). It may look like this:

```
data=thisisthejsonstringitcontainsthe&pound;hmtlcharacter&code=123&api_key=321
```

This is an issue because the &pound; is thought to be the start of a new variable so the json string is being cut.

Does this need to be encoded somehow at the VB source? Or can I do something with this when it arrives at the website? If it needs encoded by VB can anyone suggest a suitable function?

I'm using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type when posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might seem far fetched, but have you tried sending &pound urlencoded beforehand? being `%26pound`

Comment: There may be other similar characters like &amp; etc. so I'm looking for a more generic solution

Comment: Do you know a VB6 url encoding function?

Comment: Something like `Private Declare Function UrlEscape Lib "shlwapi" Alias "UrlEscapeA" (ByVal pszURL As String, ByVal pszEscaped As String, ByRef pcchEscaped As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long`?

Comment: There is no native VB6 `URLEncode()` method. You can try the function that wqw mentioned, or check the spec and roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

If you send url arguments to a webserver, you'll need to urlencode them. That's true for all arguments in formats that don't escape and can contain problematic characters themselves, which includes JSON.